# I can not push an object in JSON, but console.log() works

Tags: javascript, json

I can not push an object in JSON, but console.log() works. console.log() shows that the addition of an object, but does not appear json string?

```js
var results = [{
  "id": 0,
  "name": "Green",
  "category": "project",
  "year": 2008,
  "description": "my description",
  "comments": [{
    "rating": 5,
    "comment": "Perfect",
    "author": "Sandra",
    "date": "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
  }, {
    "rating": 4,
    "comment": "Cool",
    "author": "Milena",
    "date": "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
  }, {
    "rating": 3,
    "comment": "No bad",
    "author": "Milan",
    "date": "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
  }, {
    "rating": 4,
    "comment": "Good job",
    "author": "Toma",
    "date": "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
  }, {
    "rating": 2,
    "comment": "OK",
    "author": "Aleksandar",
    "date": "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
  }]
}];

document.getElementById('show').innerHTML = results[0].comments[1].author;

document.getElementById("sendComment").onclick = function() {

  var hg = {
    "rating": 1,
    "comment": "Hello",
    "author": "X",
    "date": "2014-09"
  }
  results[0].comments.push(hg);
  console.log(results[0].comments);
}
```

```html
<div id='show'></div>
<button id='sendComment'>Send</button>
```

Comment: Firstly, you don't have JSON, just an object, secondly, if you can see it in the console, it probably works as intended, it won't update your files and be visible in the source ?

Comment: Works fine..... So what is not working. When you update the JSON it does not update your JSON file. It just updates it in memory....

Comment: try here https://jsfiddle.net/gojk8ve3/, after refresh, all the same

Comment: how to save an object in array?

Comment: because it is not a permanent change. You can not make a permanent change with clientside JavaScript. If you want all users to see it, you need a serverside code. If it is only the people using that browser, you have localStorage.

Comment: The keyword being `"after refresh"`, it **does not** modify your files in any way

Answer (score 0):

results[0].comments is array of objects, not JSON string. All works fine. New object is added to array.

Comment: Why? If you click button next time you will see that another same object is added.

Comment: To keep data on client after page refreshing use for example JSON.stringify(results[0].comments) and localstorage